# Will an ISP give out network/traffic info upon request?

Tags: logging, internet

Nothing big, just a fear of embarrassment. I use my mom's (she pays for it) internet service to connect online and stuff. The thing is, I am nervous that she may possibly ask the ISP for some traffic analysis of where, like, I've been surfing to and worried that she might find out I often visit, uh, ...... dirty sites. I know it's nothing of a serious problem aside from major embarrassment to worry about, but I know it's going to be MAJOR embarrassment because she would find out about my ... kinks and preferences in that department.

So my basic question can worded down to: If requested, will an ISP give all info about where people have been on their infrastructure, and is there any chance they'd be likely to do this without being asked?

Comment: If you're really worried about that my friend, don't worry too much, alot of ISP's say they do, but actually don't give them, but instead of going into that, next time you need material to "reshearch", use the Tor browser https://www.torproject.org/index.html.en it is a good browser that helps you stay annonymous, have fu-... err, good luck! Lighty, experienced fapper

Comment: Thanks, Lighty. But I'm worried that they will find what's already been "uncovered". ;) I'll try from Tor now on.

Comment: don't worry, ISP's normally don't give out info, and i bet your mom doesn't even know how to spell ISP (generalizing to most mothers's knowledge of IT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many ISP's log DNS requests, so could have a record of what sites you have browsed to. This is mostly for law enforcement requirements, not generally for giving back to customers, as they should be expected to do their own logging if they want it.

That said - if you are concerned, have you checked to see if your mother is logging all DNS requests? Your router might keep logs.

More importantly, if you are going to be embarrassed about where you go online, do what Lighty suggests and protect yourself. Otherwise, I suppose you could do worse than just be prepared to have an interesting conversation with your mother :-)

Answer (score 4):

Keeping complete traffic information and giving it to customers is expensive for ISP, and there is not a lot of money to do out of embarrassing teenagers (understandably, the teenagers won't pay for it; but their parents won't pay either for obtaining that information, their offspring being already quite expensive to maintain). Consequence is that ISP don't have logs or at least don't have any process to send them to customers.

Even when the ISP have logs of "visited sites", these are meant for Law enforcement agencies, not hormonal teenagers. Unless your "kinks" involve indecent proposals to young children, commercial exchange of fissile material, or claiming that some deity commands you to kill unbelievers, then chances are that your mother will not obtain any such logs, even if she asked for them.

Bear in mind, though, that your own computers may contain a lot of traces of your network-related habits (browser history and cache, for instance). Also, it is a lot healthier in the long term to simply talk honestly with your parents, who probably know a lot more about you than you imagine (it is something that you learn when you teach some teenagers: they don't know how to conceal their thoughts; their minds are transparent; they just mistook the teacher's lassitude for obliviousness to their mental schemes).

Comment: heh.. bear in mind...

Comment: I think you are trying to be funny, but I don't think it's right to say "gender confused".

Comment: Ah ! I _knew_ someone would complain. What I pick at is the confusion, not the gender. Almost all teenagers go through a phase of confusion about their own sexuality, which translates to obnoxious behaviour and a lot of embarrassment, as is demonstrated by this question. These times are no easier for the parents than the children.

Comment: Gender confusion doesn't mean sexuality confusion. I had a friend who went through a stage thinking she might be lesbian, actually, but she still knew she was female. I know my gender and sexuality, and I am not a teenager (anymore) anyways. Thats why I am saying your assertion isn't quite correct. Not trying to nit pick....

Comment: Okay, now I'm trying to picture what sort of kink involves fissile material...